# Use of Abstract class without containing any abstract method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', "1");

    //create abstract method
    abstract class AbstractClass {

        public function getValue();

        // Common method
        public function printOut() {
        print $this->getValue() . "\n";
        }

    }

    //extend ConcreteClass1 with AbstractClass
    class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass {

        public function getValue() {
        return "ConcreteClass1";
        }

        public function prefixValue($prefix) {
        return "{$prefix}ConcreteClass1";
        }

    }

    //extend ConcreteClass2 with AbstractClass
    class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractClass {

        public function getValue() {
        return "ConcreteClass2";
        }

        public function prefixValue($prefix) {
        return "{$prefix}ConcreteClass2";
        }

    }

    //create object of ConcreteClass1
    $class1 = new ConcreteClass1;
    $class1->printOut();
    echo $class1->getValue() . "\n";

    //create object of ConcreteClass2
    $class2 = new ConcreteClass2;
    $class2->printOut();
    echo $class2->getValue() . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: and the question is ???

Comment: If you run this you will get a fatal error.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I want use abstract class but dont put any abstract method in class as you seen my code.

Comment: @u_mulder , Strange i didn`t  get any error just show blank page.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: And you see blank page because of a Fatal error.

Comment: If you don't have any abstract methods - why define class as abstract?

Comment: @u_mulder Can you please tell why i get black page instead of show any fatal error.

Comment: because you have not enabled "error reporting" and/or "display errors"

Comment: @u_mulder, there's an example when a method should be shared between classes using the same interface but can't be separated of those classes because that logic/code is exclusive for that context. Using a base `abstract` class will solve that problem and the base class shouldn't be instantiated. Nowadays, we can do that using a `trait`.

Comment: @GabrielHeming not you but OP should tell me this)))

Comment: @u_mulder It's just to show you that your question makes no sense. But anyway, the question is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, I got it  and it is possible to create abstract class without create any abstract method. :)